# MongoDB query with time comparison in array

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, datetime, nosql

I'm struggling with how to query in the field of array. Suppose I have data like:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "chapter": 1,
    "targets": [
      {
        type: 'user',
        recipientId: 1
      }
    ],
    "challenge": [
      {
        "challengeId": "ch-1",
        "targetExpired": "2020-10-14T16:25:00.000+00:00"
      },
      {
        "challengeId": "ch-2",
        "targetExpired": "2020-10-14T17:25:00.000+00:00"
      },
      {
        "challengeId": "ch-3",
        "targetExpired": "2020-10-14T18:25:00.000+00:00"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "chapter": 1,
    "targets": [
      {
        type: 'user',
        recipientId: 2
      }
    ],
    "challenge": [
      {
        "challengeId": "ch-2",
        "targetExpired": "2020-10-14T16:25:00.000+00:00"
      },
      {
        "challengeId": "ch-3",
        "targetExpired": "2020-10-14T16:25:00.000+00:00"
      },
      {
        "challengeId": "ch-4",
        "targetExpired": "2020-10-14T16:25:00.000+00:00"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "chapter": 1,
    "targets": [
      {
        type: 'user',
        recipientId: 4
      }
    ],
    "challenge": [
      {
        "challengeId": "ch-2",
        "targetExpired": "2020-10-14T16:25:00.000+00:00"
      },
      {
        "challengeId": "ch-3",
        "targetExpired": "2020-10-14T16:25:00.000+00:00"
      },
      {
        "challengeId": "ch-4",
        "targetExpired": "2020-10-14T16:25:00.000+00:00"
      },
    ]
  },
],
```

If input is `input = [1,2,4]` to check with `recipientId` the query condition is:

1. If there is "some" `targetExpired` is not expired yet (mean some `targetExpired < new Date()`) the result gets all data in DB.
2. If "all" `targetExpired` is expired, for example in `recipientId:2` all time has expired. The result I should get every collection except `recipientId: 2`

Sorry, I haven't seen any API according to this condition.
Any Idea? Thanks.